# jQuery UI dialog wont close on tap when called but will open

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, position, jquery-ui-dialog

So I'm having a hard time figuring out why my dialog boxes wont close when I they're "tapped" out of.  So far I've tried document, window, .ikon_picmap as selectors for the dialog close.  No luck.  What am I missing?

https://jsfiddle.net/089bd4kq/

Javascript:

```
//Document Ready
$(document).ready(function(){

// So the modals are hidden to start with.
$( "#p1_box" ).dialog({ autoOpen: false });
$( "#p2_box" ).dialog({ autoOpen: false });
$( "#p3_box" ).dialog({ autoOpen: false });
$( "#p4_box" ).dialog({ autoOpen: false });

// Modal placement relative to it's trigger.
$('#p1_box').dialog({position: {my:'left+5% top+4%',at:'top', of:'.p1'}});
$('#p2_box').dialog({position: {my:'left+5% top+4%',at:'top', of:'.p2'}});
$('#p3_box').dialog({position: {my:'left+5% top+4%',at:'top', of:'.p3'}});
$('#p4_box').dialog({position: {my:'left+5% top+4%',at:'top', of:'.p4'}});

$('.p1').mouseenter(function(){
    $( "#p1_box" ).dialog( "open" );
});
$('#p1_box').mouseleave(function(){
    $('#p1_box').dialog('close');
});
$('.p2').mouseenter(function(){
    $( "#p2_box" ).dialog( "open" );
});
$('#p2_box').mouseleave(function(){
    $('#p2_box').dialog('close');
});
$('.p3').mouseenter(function(){
    $( "#p3_box" ).dialog( "open" );
});
$('#p3_box').mouseleave(function(){
    $('#p3_box').dialog('close');
});
$('.p4').mouseenter(function(){
    $( "#p4_box" ).dialog( "open" );
});
$('#p4_box').mouseleave(function(){
    $('#p4_box').dialog('close');
});

//    Touch Commands
$('.p1').on("tap",function(){
    $( "#p1_box" ).dialog( "open" );
});
$('.p2').on("tap",function(){
    $( "#p2_box" ).dialog( "open" );
});
$('.p3').on("tap",function(){
    $( "#p3_box" ).dialog( "open" );
});
$('.p4').on("tap",function(){
    $( "#p4_box" ).dialog( "open" );
});


});  // End Document Ready

//On window resize (for correct modal trigger placement) - a responsive feature.
$(window).on('resize', function(){

$('#p1_box,#p2_box,#p3_box,#p4_box').dialog('close');

}); //End window resize
```

CSS

```
.p1 {
left:53%;
top:40%;
color: #0FA0CE;
}
.p2 {
left: 63%;
top: 21%;
color: #0FA0CE;
}
.p3 {
left:52%;
top:14%;
color: #0FA0CE;
}
.p4 {
left:18%;
top:65%;
color: #0FA0CE;
}
/* Picmap position markers END */

/* Global Non-Responsive Styles */
html {
width:100%;
height: 100%;
}
/* Don't show the "x" on the diag box */
.ui-dialog-titlebar-close {
visibility: hidden;
}
.ikon_picmap {
background-color: #bbbbbb;
position: relative;
display: block;

}
.ikon_picmap img {
width: 100%;
height: auto;
/*position: absolute;*/
}
.ik_p {
cursor: pointer;
height: 10px;
width: 10px;
position: absolute;
font-size: 1em;
}
```

Any help on this would be amazing!

Comment: Can you make an online demo for it? Or show us html for a single dialog.

Comment: Here's a fiddle link:
https://jsfiddle.net/089bd4kq/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to apply `mouseleave`on `.ui-dialog` instead of each dialog like

**HTML**

```
<div id="p1_box" class="p_box" title="Nose">
  <p>This is where the dog breaths from.. pretty neat.</p>
</div>
<div id="p2_box" class="p_box" title="Left Ear">
    <p>This is one of the wonderful ears used by this puppy to listen to things.</p>
</div>
<div id="p3_box" class="p_box" title="Right Ear">
    <p>Make sure he doesn't hear you out of this ear..</p>
</div>
<div id="p4_box" class="p_box" title="Toy">
    <p>A much needed thing for a puppy.  Probably shouldn't have a puppy without a toy.</p>
</div>
```

**SCRIPT**

```
$('.ui-dialog').mouseleave(function(){
    $(this).find('.p_box')
           .dialog('close'); // here p_box is elemnt for which dialog opens
});
```

One more thing don't call `dialog` multiple times for each property call it just once like,

```
$('#p1_box').dialog({
   autoOpen: false,
   position: {my:'left+5% top+4%',at:'top', of:'.p1'}
});
```

[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rohankumar1524/089bd4kq/1/)

Comment: That worked out well.  For some reason I couldn't get the box to close out on tap on my previous attempts. I don't understand why mouseleave works when tapping outside of the ui-dialog.  I was under the impression it had to be 

    on('tap', function(){});